# how to trace java script program line by line in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Please let me know how to trace or debug the java script  and jquery in visual studio 2008 and 2010. Because I have java script and jquery programme. Please let me know how to do it.

Thanks
PBN

Comment: I would better prefer firebug for firefox or built-in debugger in Chrome, IE.

Answer (score 2):

IE8 and later has a built-in Javascript debugger, so you don't need a separate debugger/IDE anymore.

That said, IE supports using the Active Scripting debugger (and has done since at least IE4) so you can debug Javascripts in IE using any competent Windows debugger, including Visual Studio.

Assuming you want to use VS, do this:

1. Internet Options > Advanced > Check "Enable script debugging"
2. Launch VS and launch IE in the script you want to debug
3. In VS, go Debug > Attach to process (or Tools > Attach to process, depending on whether or not you have a project loaded)
4. Select `iexplore.exe` from the processes list, it should say "Script" in the Types column, so you know its working.
5. Use the newly-appeared "Script Explorer" window to inspect, set-breakpoint, and debug currently-loaded scripts in the current IE session.

Comment: +1. For all other browser - F12 will bring developer tools to debug scripts. Note that IE have nice "format script" option that makes debugging minified script much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do it in Visual Studio?

I do it in my browser's console window.. You can usually access it via F12. In IE, you can check developer tools. In Chrome, ctrl+shift+J will open the console.

Answer (score 0):

One can use Firebug to debug in Firefox, Firebug lite in Chrome, IE web developer in Internet explorer.

Comment: You phrased the asnwer as if FireBug is the only tool to debug Javascript... Consider editing...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the **F12** in the **Internet Explorer**. If you have IE as the default browser for the debugging.
If you are using **Google chrome**, then **cntrl+Shift+j** will start the debugger and that too has a nice display and it is quite easy to understand as it traces the mouse movements as well.